# Phoenix - Can't broadcast to channel from iex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I tried opening IEX via: iex -S mix and iex -S mix phoenix.server

Here is my user_socket:

```
defmodule Final.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  channel "keywords*", Final.KeywordsChannel 
  transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket  

  def connect(_params, socket) do
      {:ok, socket}
    end
  def id(_socket), do: nil  

end
```

And KeywordsChannel:

```
defmodule Final.KeywordsChannel do
  use Final.Web, :channel
  use Phoenix.Channel      

  def join("keywords",_, socket) do
    IO.puts "helloo"
     {:ok, "aaaa", socket}
  end

  def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
    IO.puts "hello"
    broadcast! socket, "new_msg", %{body: body}
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_out("new_msg", payload, socket) do
    IO.puts "hell"
    push socket, "new_msg", payload
    {:noreply, socket}
  end


end
```

I try calling it like:

Final.Endpoint.broadcast("keywords", "new_msg", %{body: "b"})

Final.Endpoint.broadcast! "keywords", "new_msg", %{body: "b"}
...

And every other variation I could think off, but never receive any response, just ":ok"

Using 1.3.2 elixir with phoenix 1.2.1

Comment: Check your typo: `channel "keywords:*", Final.KeywordsChannel` and try it again.

Comment: No difference, anyway join/3 works(via js) just handle_in doesn't seem to register :)

Comment: When you're using `YourApp.Endpoint.broadcast!/3` in `iex` you will receive `:ok`.If you want to see the response then listen your event from client browser: `channel.on("new_msg", payload => { console.log(payload) }`